CORS headers not allowed in Django
I am developing an API in Django and using next js as the frontend. But each time I try to call the back end to the next js fronend I get on the console
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`

I also get this
Login error: 
AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"

I did the following

I added to the first line of the middleware section 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', to my settings.py after install django cors headers
Stopped and restarted the server
I also ```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost:3000',
'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
'http://0.0.0.0:3000',

]
and yet i still get the problem

Does this answer your question? Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin 'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Have you done

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]

?

hi yes i have. Its also done
